# Clicking row in table 'checking' checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I hope this is the right area, as it is more theoretical than anything else. I am currently working on a page where a user can select one or many rows to edit by clicking a checkbox in the leftmost column and clicking an `Edit` button. I haven't decided if I wanted to try programming this feature, but would it be possible to effectively **hide** the checkboxes and use some sort of javascript or jquery to make clicking a row in a table equivalent to checking the corresponding row's checkbox? I have just started working with javascript and jquery, and I am baffled by how powerful this can be. Please inform me if this type of functionality is possible and if so, what is a general approach to achieving this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doable. Here's how:

[jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/etejog/3/edit)

HTML

```
<table border=1>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Something 1</td><td>Something else 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Something 2</td><td>Something else 2</td></tr>    
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Something 3</td><td>Something else 3</td></tr>    
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox"></td><td>Something 4</td><td>Something else 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').parent('td').hide(); // If JS disabled, checkboxes are still visible

$('table tr').click( function() {
    var $chk = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
    $chk.prop('checked',!$chk.prop('checked'));
    $(this).toggleClass('selected'); // To show something happened
});
```

CSS

```
tr.selected{
   background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: Does `find` guarantee it will find the correct checkbox? I could see a case where it would find the next row's checkbox.. I like your implementation of `$(this).toggleClass('selected');`. I've been typing `css.("background"..` This will make testing much easier.

Comment: Well I'm assuming there's going to be one checkbox only. If not, you can give it a class and use something like `$('.chkbox_class')` instead. This is always my preferred option, which assures you'll find the right element.

Comment: Can you explain how exactly `$chk.prop('checked',!$chk.prop('checked'));` works?

Comment: `$chk.prop('checked')` returns a `boolean` for the current selected state of the checkbox. the `!` will turn `true` to `false` and vice versa. This will pass the opposite of the current state of the checkbox back to same checkbox. Essentially, this is just replicating the click action

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is perfectly achievable, although you might like to consider the accessibility implications in the event that somebody has JavaScript disabled in their browser.

There are a number of approaches you could take. By way of example, you could use a `click` handler something like the following (untested):

```
$(document).on('click', '#yourtable tr', function(evt) {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

This would give each `tr` in your table (with id `#yourtable`) the class `selected` which you could then either style via CSS and/or read back via another piece of jQuery.

Within the event handler you could also perform other actions to record the selection, such as updating a hidden input field, posting straight back to the server, or checking the existing checkbox (which could optionally be hidden if you prefer).

Comment: Upvoted for making the case of JavaScipt disabled evident. To counter this, I would simply use javascript to hide the checkboxes also right (as opposed to a hidden field or something)? That way, the site still works with JS disabled?

Comment: Yep, that should work - it's progressive enhancement. Providing a basic implementation that works for everybody, and then layering richer functionality on top.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [simple implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/PM6JX/) of the requested functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr').click(function(e) {
        var $checkbox = $(this).find('input');
        var isChecked = $checkbox.prop('checked');

        if (isChecked) {
            $checkbox.removeProp('checked');
        }
        else {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', 'checked');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Trouble is, on clicking the `tr` again, the checkbox will not be unchecked, which is expected behavior. Also, `prop` is preferred to `attr` in this case